# php how to loop through existing values and put them together?

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="text[0]">
    <a id="AddMore">Add more fields</a>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"> 
</form>
```

The #AddMore adds input elements (with jQuery) where the number iterates. So when you click it once you get:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="text[0]">
    <input type="text" name="text[1]">
    <a id="AddMore">Add more fields</a>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"> 
</form>
```

When it is submitted, I want to grab the values of the existing inputs and add it to my $message string. I thought of it something like this:

```
$message = "Text number: 1 contains: " . $_POST['text[0]'] . "\r\n" // . $extraInput; ???
for ($x = 1; $x < 20; $x++) { // 20 = max number of inputs
    if(isset($_POST['text[$x]']) && $_POST['text[$x]'] != ''){
        $extraInput-$x .= "Text number: " . $x + 1 " contains: " . $_POST['text[$x]'] . "\r\n"; // how to add this to $message?
    } else {
        $extraInput-$x .= "";
    }
```

I know my php is not correct, but I put it here anyway so you would understand my intentions better. The right way to use it is what I like to know/learn.

For example, when I click 'Add more fields' twice. I want php to put the following string into $message:

```
$message = "Text number: 1 contains: " . $_POST['text[0]'] . "\r\n" . "Text number: 2 contains: " . $_POST['text[1]'] . "\r\n" . "Text number: 3 contains: " . $_POST['text[2]'] . "\r\n";
```

That's what I finally want to mail using:

```
mail($to,$subject,$message);
```

Comment: Doesnt PHP return an array for `$_POST['text']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `<input type="text">` have the attribute `name` as `text[0]`, `text[1]`, etc, in your php code they values are not in `$_POST[text[n]]`, but in `$_POST[text][n]`.

So, you can obtain desired output in this way:

```
$message = '';
foreach( $_POST['text'] as $key => $val )
{
    $message .= "Text number: ".($key+1)." contains: {$val}\r\n";
}
```

Or — if you want skip empty values — in this way:

```
$message = '';
$index   = 1;
foreach( $_POST['text'] as $val )
{
    if( $val )
    {
        $message .= "Text number: ".($index++)." contains: {$val}\r\n";
    }
}
```

Edit: please also note that there is no need to check is `$_POST[text][n]` if set, because all elements of an array are set, either if they are empty.

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it :

```
if(0 < sizeof($_POST['text']))
{
    $message = '<ol>';
    foreach($_POST['text'] as $text)
    {
        if(false === empty($text))
            $message .= "<li>".$text."</li>";
    }
    $message = '</ol>';
}else{
    $message = "void";
}
```